# I programmatically need to notice when connman has processed its config file (and has set an IP or not)

Tags: linux, systemd, connman

How can I wait in my user space program until `connman` has finished the network configuration on Linux booting? (Unfortunately, this is not `Wants=connman.service`.)

After systemd service `connman` is up, my user space program starts via `systemd` service (`Wants=network.target connman.service`), and it wants to read the network configuration via C function `getifaddrs()` (e.g. `ifa->ifa_addr` and `ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family`). Now two things can happen, either `connman` reads an explicitely unconfigured network (`IPv4=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0`) or a certain network configuration (e.g. `IPv4=192.168.0.50/255.255.255.0/0.0.0.0`) from its config file. For some reasons my program has to wait on a certain code line until `connman` has finished its setup with one of both cases. How do I do that?

All I found in the `systemd` synchronisation possibilities were points of times when the `connman` service is up (`Wants=connman.service`) which does not mean it has processed its config file, it's before that!!!), and secondly, `network-online.target` for when an IP address is configured (which does not include the case of `0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0` in the connman config file).

---

addon: I noticed an IP address is set during Linux booting as soon as "Link is up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off" is printed on console. How do I detect that in my user program?

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, all I found is this workaround. The start script of my service looks into connman's .config file and searches for the line with "IPv4=", and in case it's all 0.0.0.0 there I can immediately start my application or otherwise I have to loop in that script until ifconfig reports it has set an IP address for that certain network adapter interface.